How to only execute/install dotnet from wix Installer
I have some problem with install my app.
My application was created in WIX. One of the step is install dotnet runtime 8.0.6 .
I don't need create additional Directiory to aplication I need only to install/remove that dotnet.
How to execute/install dotnet to default directory ?
I have Directiory section also I have a my components with file I have copy but I don't have copy files I have only install dotnet or remove and that's all. And this is a problem with this task.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
             xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
          <?include WAAVariables.wxi ?>
          </Product>
        
          <Fragment>
            <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
              <Directory Id="USERPROFILEFOLDER" />
              <Directory Id="System64Folder" Name="System64Folder">
                <Directory Id="config" Name="config">
                  <Directory Id="systemprofile" Name="systemprofile" />
                </Directory>
              </Directory>
              <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="DIR_MICPROGRAMFOLDER" Name="Micro">
                  <Directory Id="DIR_LABPROGRAMFOLDER" Name="Lab">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WAA">
                      <Directory Id="SSL" Name="ssl">
                        <Directory Id="SSLPRIVATE" Name="private" />
                      </Directory>
                      <Directory Id="RUNTIMES" Name="runtimes">
                        <Directory Id="WIN" Name="win">
                          <Directory Id="LIB" Name="lib">
                            <Directory Id="NET80" Name="net8.0" />
                          </Directory>
                        </Directory>
                      </Directory>
                    </Directory>
                  </Directory>
                </Directory>
              </Directory>
            </Directory>
            <SetDirectory Id="USERPROFILEFOLDER" Value="[%USERPROFILE]\" Sequence="first" />
        </Fragment>
        <Fragment>
            <CustomAction Id="DotnetInstallCommand"
            Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
             ExeCommand="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]dotnet-runtime-8.0.6-win-x64.exe&quot; /install /quiet /norestart"
             Execute="immediate"
             Return="asyncNoWait"
             Impersonate="no"/>
        
            <CustomAction Id="RemoveDotnetInstallCommand"
            Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
            ExeCommand="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]dotnet-runtime-8.0.6-win-x64.exe&quot; /uninstall /quiet /norestart"
           Execute="immediate"
           Return="asyncNoWait"
           Impersonate="no"/>
   <InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action="DotnetInstallCommand" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>    
     <Custom Action="RemoveDotnetInstallCommand" After="InstallFinalize">Installed AND 
      REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
   </InstallExecuteSequence>
 </Fragment>
</Wix>

